# CSRF cookie not set when calling POST request API view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have encountered a weird behavior as it works with one view but does not with another.
Django 3.2 and rest framework 3.13.1 are currently installed within the venv.

When I call the view I get the error message: CSRF validation failed, reason CSRF cookie not set.
This view uses its authentication class that extends TokenAuthentication.

```
class APIKeyAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def authenticate(self, request):

    # try to get api key via X-API_KEY
    api_key = request.META.get("HTTP_X_API_KEY")

    # try to get api key via Authorization
    if not api_key:
        api_key = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")

    if not api_key:
        return None

    platform_id, api_user = self.validate_api_token(api_key)
    return api_user, None
```

That class is used as default within rest framework:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "api.authentification.APIKeyAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
    ),
   "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
```

Endpoints are:

```
path("v1/combinedEntries", VerifyV1OrderView.as_view()),
path("order/verify/", VerifyOrderView.as_view()),
```

Classes:

```
class VerifyV1OrderView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CombinedEntryV1Serializer
    authentication_classes = (APIKeyAuthentication,)
```

and

```
class VerifyOrderView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CombinedEntrySerializer
    authentication_classes = (APIKeyAuthentication,)
```

so I do not understand the error I even removed the session authentication from the config but without any change.
I am using Postman to send the requests but the error occurs also when using curl.

Has someone an idea what the problem could be?
Thanks and regards.
Matt

Comment: I think you have logged in admin portal also in same browser, in which you are testing these endpoints. Because admin portal use session authentication. try to log out first from admin portal and then test or use different browser or incognito window.

Comment: try clearing the csrf cookies from postman, go to cookies and clear the one for your host